# Specify word length in agrep?

Tags: agrep

I am using `agrep` to find similar spelling words, for example:

```
agrep -1 hack /usr/share/dict/words
```

But it returns too many words, so I also hope the length of the word is same as the keyword. How can I specify that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using 1 agrep

The key to using `agrep` is to recognize that you can control the cost for things like adding, substituting, and deleting characters. For insertion it's the `-I` switch. For deletion it's `-D`.

```
$ agrep -1 -I2 -D2 '^hack$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

#### Example

```
$ agrep -1 -I2 -D2 '^hack$' /usr/share/dict/words
back
cack
fack
haak
hack
haik
hank
hark
hask
hawk
heck
hick
hock
huck
Jack
jack
lack
Mack
mack
Pack
pack
rack
sack
tack
Wack
wack
yack
Zack
zack
```

#### Details

So if we set the cost of insertion 1 higher than the number of errors we're willing to tolerate, and do the same for the cost of deletions, we'll never insert or delete any characters, thus maintaining our length, which is the length of the pattern we're matching, `hack`, i.e. 4.

So in the above command we've set our margin of error at 1 (`-1`). We've set our cost of doing and insertion or a deletion to 2 (`-I2 -D2`). And we've guarded our results so that they only match strings that are whole words which begin and end with our pattern, (`^hack$`).

**NOTE:** The caret (`^`) means the beginning of the string, and the dollar sign (`$`) the end. These are called anchors.

#### Using 2 agreps

As an alternative you can also use 2 agreps.

```
$ agrep '^[a-zA-Z]{4}$' /usr/share/dict/words | agrep -1 'hack'
```

#### Example

```
$ agrep '^[a-zA-Z]{4}$' /usr/share/dict/words | agrep -1 'hack'
back
cack
Chac
Chak
dhak
fack
haak
hack
haik
hake
hako
haku
hank
hark
hask
hawk
heck
hick
hock
huck
Jack
jack
lack
Mack
mack
Pack
pack
rack
sack
Shak
tack
thak
Wack
wack
yack
Zack
zack
```

#### Details

The first `agrep` is tasked with finding the set of strings that are 4 characters in length. The second `agrep` reduces this set further to only strings matching your pattern of `hack` with a single error allowed.

Comment: Thanks. What does "^hack$" mean?

Comment: It anchors the string making sure that it's the beginning and the end of the line.

Comment: but "ack" doesn't begin or end with "hack"?

Comment: @Tim - yeah I'm just noticing that, investigating.

Comment: @Tim - see updates, figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you could specify that to `agrep`
However, you might be able to use the shell to solve your problem. For example, with `bash`. In the following:
Set the variable `keyword` to `hack` Set the length of `keyword` into
   `l` 
Pass `l` into `awk` via a variable named `limit`, and specify
   that `awk` print records whose length (as determined by the awk
   built-in function `length`) is equal to `limit`

```
keyword=hack; l=${#keyword};
agrep -1 $keyword /usr/share/dict/words | awk -v limit=$l 'length == limit'
Jack
Mack
back
hack
hake
hank
hark
hawk
heck
hick
hock
jack
lack
pack
rack
sack
tack
yack
```

Comment: Thanks! can you explain "awk -v limit=$l 'length() == limit'"? Is length() a function? How does it know what its argument is?